# Microsoft Graph API - Add member to group ERROR 404 Invalid version: Groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, power-automate

I am creating a Power Automate, Powerapp that creates a user in my O365 tenant. I have most things squared away, but when I attempt to add the user to the chosen Distrolist,o365 groups, or security groups i get a response error of "invalid Version: groups" It comes with a 404 error, but the group ID's are correct, i have already, by this time, performed a license call on the user so it is accessable to manipulate and "GET". So I do not understand what that error means. There is only one functioning version for Graph (v1.0). Can anyone help me. I will try and post as much raw code from the Power automate as possible.

The FLow input: [Flow Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9KJs.png)
Flow output below:

```json
{
   "statusCode":404,
   "headers":{
      "request-id":"*******-00f8-4fb8-976b-976445fbff35",
      "client-request-id":"f6f1574c-00f8-4fb8-976b-976445fbff35",
      "x-ms-ags-diagnostic":"{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"Central US\",\"Slice\":\"SliceC\",\"Ring\":\"2\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"RoleInstance\":\"AGSFE_IN_21\"}}",
      "Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000",
      "x-ms-apihub-cached-response":"true",
      "Cache-Control":"private",
      "Date":"Thu, 27 Aug 2020 22:43:12 GMT",
      "Content-Length":"225",
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
   },
   "body":{
      "error":{
         "code":"ResourceNotFound",
         "message":"Invalid version: groups",
         "innerError":{
            "date":"2020-08-27T22:43:13",
            "request-id":"*******-00f8-4fb8-976b-976445fbff35"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the Graph API connectors schema:

```
  /groups/{id}/members/$ref:
patch:
  responses:
    default:
      description: default
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          value:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              properties:
                id: {type: string, description: id}
            description: value
  summary: Add-GroupMember
  operationId: Add-GroupMember
  parameters:
  - {name: id, in: path, required: true, type: string}
  - {name: 'content-type:', in: header, required: false, type: string, default: application/json,
    x-ms-visibility: advanced}
  - name: body
    in: body
    required: false
    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        members@odata.bind:
          type: array
          items: {type: string}
          description: members@odata.bind
```

I hope all this helps. Let me know if you need anything else, but I am kind of new to this stuff so explaining this will be useful.

Comment: did you try adding member using Postman? did it worked for you? I suggest try using postman and see if you get success. Once you do you can move to Power automate.

Comment: @AnkUser - I don't have the ability to use Postman with the connector i setup for my org i have to test it directly from the connector. What i found is that it doesn't like the majority of groups i am selecting because they are Distribution lists. Even though they are managed in the cloud it won't let me add to them. How can /groups list the distribution lists, but it won't Post to them?